# How to apply on change event on nested select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i perform on change event on  below select option and what i need to do disable the select box.I can't change anything in the code,i am using some in build code

```
<div id="status" class="leaf">
  <label class="control select" title>
      <span class="wrap">status</span>
    <select>
      <option value="active"></option>
        </select>
   </label>
</div>
```

thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: what is your problem.? cant you select it using Jquery?

Comment: Please include some attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: I'm not sure the select will ever fire the change event since it only has one value.

Comment: @kevin , i have multiple option

Comment: @jasim It would be helpful if you noted that in your example or used the actual HTML causing your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using jQuery in your code then try this one.

```
$(document).on('click','#status select',function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).prop({disabled:true});
});
```

Comment: Thanks manish,it just working perfectly,
i just made one small change 'click' to change
thanks dude :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just disable it with jQuery:

```
$("select").prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do the below. But if more than one select then it will cause issue.

```
$( "select" ).change(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

**UPDATE**

Another option just thought of, might work for you.

```
$( "#status" ).find( "select" ).change(function() {
        var selectedVal = $(this).val();
        $(this).prop({disabled:true});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
$("select").change( function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iqijAKEc)

Answer (score 0):

Ive done this before and it has worked for me:

Here is the simplest way changing HTML CODE:

```
<select name="ab" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) doSomething();">
    <option value="-1">--</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option> 
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

Works both with mouse selection and keyboard Up/Down keys whes select is focused.

Without changing HTML CODE:

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Please check this for more information on this function:

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: This part `<select name="ab" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) doSomething();">` is very bad practice.